# Dijkstra algorithm with Neo spring boot

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I would like to ask, how could I find Dijkstra with Spring boot.

I currently use spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j library to map Neo4j with my java classes.

I wanna use now Dijkstra and All path algorithms from the  org.neo.graphalgo [graphalgo](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html#dijkstra-org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander-org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.InitialBranchState-org.neo4j.graphalgo.CostEvaluator-) library.

Is it possible to do this? Or any other alternate ways would equally be appreciated.

EDIT------------------------

I have mapped all my Neo4j Nodes like following in Java and they work. I just want to now use this graphalgo library that you mention. I am confused how I can use it now.

btw all the code is here: https://github.com/aamalik/neo4j-gtfs

```
@NodeEntity
public class Stop {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Property(name="lon")
    private double longitude;

    @Property(name="lat")
    private double latitude;

    @Property(name="id")
    private String stopId;
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted it, can you please tell me, why?

Answer (score 1):

To use graph algorithms for Neo4j you need [neo4j-graph-algo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo) maven dependency. But according to [Spring Boot Dependency versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) it is not being provided, so you have to manually include it in the dependencies section of the POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-graph-algo</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use [methods](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html#method.summary) provided by GraphAlgoFactory, for example, to calculate cheapest path between *start* [node](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html) and *end* node:

```
public Path calculateCheapestPath(Node start, Node end) {
    PathFinder<WeightedPath> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.dijkstra(PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections(), "cost");
    return finder.findSinglePath(start, end);
}
```

See [here](http://fooo.fr/~vjeux/github/github-recommandation/db/doc/manual/html/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html) for graph algorithm examples.

Comment: thanks, but I get a Java object when I in Spring do a @Query. How can I map this java object to expander or other GraphAlgoFactory native elements

Comment: Can you add a code snippet to further explain your problem? What do you mean by mapping object to expander and native elements?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this question for a follow-up to what I did. 
[Dijkstra algorithm with Neo spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501307/dijkstra-algorithm-with-neo-spring-boot)